# How do I test if all items in an array are identical?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I can generate a few lines of code that will do this but I'm wondering if there's a nice clean Rubyesque way of doing this. In case I haven't been clear, what I'm looking for is an array method that will return true if given (say) `[3,3,3,3,3]` or `["rabbits","rabbits","rabbits"]` but will return false with `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `["rabbits","rabbits","hares"]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
class Array
  def same_values?
    self.uniq.length == 1
  end
end


[1, 1, 1, 1].same_values?
[1, 2, 3, 4].same_values?
```

What about this one? It returns false for an empty array though, you can change it to <= 1 and it will return true in that case. Depending on what you need.

Comment: That's pretty elegant. I can just use the .uniq.length == 1 directly in my code rather than the way you've done it (I'm only using it once so I'm keeping it DRY). It'd be nice if there was a built in .same_values? method. I don't need to worry about the empty array case in my code as a) it shouldn't come up in my situation and b) if it did I would want it to return false.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `uniq` uses `hash` and `eql?` and not `==` which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: One could of course extend this to nested arrays with self.flatten.uniq.lenth == 1

Comment: You could use the [one?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001501) method: `uniq.one?`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, `self.` is not needed and you misspelled `length`.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm `uniq.one?` doesn't handle nil values eg; `a = ["3", nil, nil, nil]`, `a.same_values? ` returns true

Answer (score 82):

You can use `Enumerable#all?` which returns true if the given block returns true for all the elements in the collection.

```
array.all? {|x| x == array[0]}
```

(If the array is empty, the block is never called, so doing `array[0]` is safe.)

Comment: How about `!(array.any? {|x| x != array[0]})`? It won't iterate though all the elements after the first occurrence of a different value.

Comment: @Nu-hin Neither will `all?`.

Comment: This will use less memory and could possibly be faster than the accepted answer because it will bail out at the first mismatch. The accepted answer loads all elements into a hash, then counts the number of keys in that hash.

Comment: @aidan is right. As well as saving memory it saves the cpu time used in consuming that memory. This will be significant in comparison to the simple equality comparison here.

Answer (score 11):

I too like preferred answer best, short and sweet. If all elements were from the same Enumerable class, such as Numeric or String, one could use

```
def all_equal?(array) array.max == array.min end
```

Comment: The objects don't need to be in the same class, they merely need to be able to implement `<=>` (the spaceship operator).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The spaceship operator causes this code to fail if the objects are of different types.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use:

```
array.reduce { |x,y| x == y ? x : nil }
```

It may fail when `array` contains `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
array = ["rabbits","rabbits","hares", nil, nil]
array.uniq.compact.length == 1
```